# how can I access a select object item and make the first option selected

Tags: javascript, dom

how can I access a select object item and make the first option selected.
the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
object.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selectObject.selectedIndex = 0;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KVnKH/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
$("#select_Id option:first").attr("selected",true);
```

Or maybe:

```
$("#select_id").find("option").first().attr("selected", true);
```

**No jQuery**

```
document.getElementById("select_id").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: @Usman: But it is always relevant. jQuery is Javascript after all.

Comment: @Purmou then I should tell that "If you consider using jQuery..." .

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/XpDJ9/

```
var drp = document.getElementById("drp");

drp.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Updated for first option selected - http://jsfiddle.net/XpDJ9/1/

```
drp.selectedIndex = 0;
```